# Using VBA can I access another computer's desktop that is on the same network as me?

Tags: vba, command-prompt

I finished a program for one of my colleagues but the final section of the program needs to start an executable file which is on a different PC. In this case the PC being used is called `SYS1-PC` and it needs to tell `EDITING-PC` that it should double click an executable file on its desktop.

I thought it might be something like this:

```
RDPWindow = Shell("C:\Users\FORMAT.PLIM\Desktop\testing.exe /v:" & "[IP ADDRESS]", 1)
```

But I just get `file not found`. Now I am not sure does that mean it has found the computer or does that mean it looked for that on my own C drive?

Cheers for any help

Comment: You can't simply *tell* a remote PC to double-click something. You need to go through the correct interfaces to do that. It's not clear from your question what the current situation is when the error happens. Do you have a remote desktop connection established? Are you employing some other means to access the remote PC? Furthermore, the [tag:ms-access] tag seems to not fit - there's nothing in your question that relates to MS Access.

Comment: The situation just stuck in the 1 computer for now. With no connection working. I was hoping to use RDP and then via cmd run the program. I added the Access tag because this runs out of an MS access database, wasnt sure if that was relevant.

Comment: It looked on your own C drive. I doubt can accomplish this due to network security. If possible, I expect have to be able to set up a drive mapping to the other PC folder or know the UNC path to the other PC.

Comment: So the quickest way to solve this would to simply run the starting program on the second computer so it runs the relevant executable as itself.

Comment: Yes, might be able to use TaskScheduler to run a script that opens the executable. I use VBScript to automate opening an Access file.

Comment: @June7 having the correct path to the file (assuming it's actually reachable from a remote PC) is only part of the problem. I understood OP wants to execute the remote file on the remote PC *as local user on that PC*. As I'm understanding it, they'll need to actually log in to do so. (That was referring to your first comment - seems you understood it the same way.)

Comment: Yeah the starting PC would be telling the second PC to run that executable. So as Inarion said. As if someone was sat there double clicking

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it seems to me you might be better served asking that specific bit of your problem on [Serverfault SE](https://serverfault.com/) or maybe on [Superuser SE](https://superuser.com/), although the former seems a better fit.